# Is there an analogue of drupal-like jquery plugin for a tree view with drag and drop functionality?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a jquery plugin with the same functionality as drupal`s standard tree view with infinite nesting used for all kind of taxonomy terms managing and etc.

Is there an analogue of such kind of plugin and maybe you could point me what is the basic of it?